# Problemas com o Composer

Tags: composer

To aprendendo a usar o Composer padrão psr-4, a classe não está sendo encontrada.

Meu index onde a classe usuário não é encontrada:

```
<?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

$user = new \App\Vendas\Usuario();
$user->cadastrar('David', 30);

$p1 = new \App\Vendas\Produto();
$p2 = new \App\Vendas\Produto();

$p1->cadastrar(1, 'produto1');
$p2->cadastrar(2, 'produto2');

$c = new \App\Vendas\Compra();

$c->cadastrar( array('p1' => $p1, 'p2' => $p2), $user);

echo $c->imprimir();

$e = new \App\Estoque\Estoque();
echo $e->getTotal();
?>
```

Meu arquivo composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload":
    {
        "psr-4":{"App\\":"App/"}
    }
}
```

Estrutura de diretório:

```
App
---Vendas
    Compra.php
    Usuario.php
    Produto.php
---Estoque
    Produto.php
    Estoque.php
---vendor
composer.json
index.php
```

Comment: O diretório `vendor` está dentro de `App`?

Comment: Tente trocar `App/` por `./` no composer e atualize (`composer dump-autoload`)

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss Esta dentro de App sim.

Comment: Se está em `App/vendor`, no seu `index.php` deveria ser `require_once('App/vendor/autoload.php')`, caso contrário não conseguirá incluir o arquivo. A questão é, por que `vendor` está em `App`?

Comment: E vendor deveria estar aonde? A solução do @Guilherme Gostamilam funcionou, eu queria entender porque.

Comment: Tá tudo dentro de App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o nome da pasta raiz não é considerado, ao definir `"App\\": "App/"` ele tentará encontrar a pasta `[...]/App/App` sendo o primeiro a pasta raiz do projeto e o segundo a pasta raiz do namespace `App`, a estrutura correta de diretórios para o seu autoload seria algo assim:

```
MeuProjetoIncrivel
---App
------Vendas
      Compra.php
      Usuario.php
      Produto.php
------Estoque
      Produto.php
      Estoque.php
---vendor
composer.json
index.php
```